# Importing DICOM image path (using MacBook, google collab) but getting [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I'm having trouble reading the file path that contains a DICOM image. I'm familiar with retrieving a file path on Windows and reading it but I'm currently using a MacBook and it seems a little different. Can anyone shed some tips and guide me to correct solution?

```
import os
f = open (os.path.expanduser("/Users/lynova/Downloads/MRI_CV/SER00006/IMG00001.dcm"))
ds=dicom.read_file(f)
```

Comment: I believe you should remove the first ~

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli I removed the tilde but still receiving the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the os.path.expanduser function, unless you're using the tilde for the home folder [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)

```
import os
f = open ("/Users/lynova/Downloads/MRI_CV/SER00006/IMG00001.dcm","rb")
ds=dicom.read_file(f)
```

Change the **rb** to **r** if the DICOM file is not binary.

Comment: Leopolodo Keller, it worked on my end! Thank you for your assistance!